# Finding hyper links in Microsoft powerpoint 2010

Tags: html, hyperlink, powerpoint

How do you find all hyper links in a power point document at once?

Ctrl + f only gives me the values, but I am unable to find all of the hyper links at once that are within the whole document

Comment: If you're looking for a way to do this w/o writing code, this is the wrong place to ask.  Try the sister SuperUser site instead. If you're looking for a way to do it in code, the community expects to see at least a little effort on your part.  HInt: google POWERPOINT SHOW HYPERLINK and there'll be at least one hit on the first page of results that includes VBA to list hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy-pasting from [HERE](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00674_Show_Me-_The_hyperlinks_in_my_presentation.htm)

You apparently can do it with VBA:

```
Sub ShowMeTheHyperlinks()
' Lists the slide number, shape name and address
' of each hyperlink

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oHl As Hyperlink

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks
            If oHl.Type = msoHyperlinkShape Then
                MsgBox "HYPERLINK IN SHAPE" _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "Slide: " & vbTab & oSl.SlideIndex _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "Shape: " & oHl.Parent.Parent.Name _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "Address:" & vbTab & oHl.Address _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "SubAddress:" & vbTab & oHl.SubAddress
            Else
                ' it's text
                MsgBox "HYPERLINK IN TEXT" _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "Slide: " & vbTab & oSl.SlideIndex _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "Shape: " & oHl.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "Address:" & vbTab & oHl.Address _
                    & vbCrLf _
                    & "SubAddress:" & vbTab & oHl.SubAddress
            End If
        Next    ' hyperlink
    Next    ' Slide

End Sub
```

There's a walkthrough on how to use VBA code in powerpoint [HERE](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00033_How_do_I_use_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint.htm)